# Javascript not selecting background color from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to make a subheader with several different colors, almost like the one on the [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com) page. The only difference is that instead of having specific colors, I am trying to get it to randomly select a color from a Javascript array.

I have already defined the hexadecimal colors I want to use, the problem I am facing is that it isn't displaying it correctly (at all for that matter) in the HTML page. Can someone walk me through how to fix this? If this can be accomplished using jQuery, that would work as well.

---

Here is what I have so far:

**Javascript:**

```
var colors = ['#3399FF', '#44A1FF', '#55AAFF', '#65B2FF', '#76BBFF', '#87C3FF', '#98CCFF', '#A9D4FF', '#BADDFF', '#CAE5FF', '#DBEEFF', '#ECF6FF'];

onload = changeColor();

function changeColor() {
    subheader.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="subheader" id="sub1"></div>
<div class="subheader" id="sub2"></div>
<div class="subheader" id="sub3"></div>
<!-- Repeats till id="sub20" -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#3399FF;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.subheader {
    height:2%;
    width:5%;
    top:10%;
    position:absolute;
}
#sub1 {left:0;}
#sub2 {left:5%;}
#sub3 {left:10%;}
/* Repeats till #sub20 */
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ShaunLoftin/2asvho0c/)

---

Also, if there is a way to shorten my rather extensive HTML and CSS maybe by using something like `:nth-child()`, please include that in your answer if you know how. Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var colors = ['#3399FF', '#44A1FF', '#55AAFF', '#65B2FF', '#76BBFF', '#87C3FF', '#98CCFF', '#A9D4FF', '#BADDFF', '#CAE5FF', '#DBEEFF', '#ECF6FF'];

onload = changeColor();



    function changeColor() {
        subheader=document.getElementsByClassName('sub-header');
        for(i=0;i<subheader.length;i++){
        subheader[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        }
    }
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2asvho0c/4/

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. But before I mark it as the correct answer please edit your answer to explain what I did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin, subheader wasn't defined. I have defined it, and since document.getElementsByClassName return NodeList (array-like object), we can loop through it, and change style of each element, in this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You have a small problem with the JavaScript

### JavaScript

```
var colors = ['#3399FF', '#44A1FF', '#55AAFF', '#65B2FF', '#76BBFF', '#87C3FF', '#98CCFF', '#A9D4FF', '#BADDFF', '#CAE5FF', '#DBEEFF', '#ECF6FF'],
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-header'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
  var color = color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  elems[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2asvho0c/7/)**

### Explanation

The error with your code was that you had types `sub-header.style` the compiler assumes `sub-header` is a variable but it isn't defined. What we have done is added the variable (`elems`), looped through it, and applied the color. Another issue is that `-` aren't supported for variable names. I hope this helped

Comment: This works but it doesn't apply to all 20 of the subheader blocks.

Comment: Your explanation is not entirely correct. The OP's code tries to subtract `header.style` from `sub`. Hyphens are not allowed inside variable names.